# How do I remove the default Google Search Value from Google Search box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a little jQuery to "hide" the initial value in a Google Search box when you click in the box and I am missing something.

Here is the search box code:

```
<div id="search_box">
<form action="http://mfrp.ehclients.com/search_results" id="cse-search-box">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="017425724926122041548:1ccj3d-e1-s" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:9" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q" value="Search..." size="31" />
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=en"></script>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#q').click(function() {           
  if($(this).val() == 'Search...') 
  $(this).val('');
  });
</script>
```

Only problem is, it doesn't work. Here is the [page](http://mfrp.ehclients.com/).

I would appreciate some help sorting this out.

Thanks,

Forrest

Comment: Try console.log( $( this ).val() ) and see what it's giving you.

Comment: When I paste your javascript code into firebug and run it the box does what it should.
Edit: shot in the dark, try $(document).ready(function() { /*code*/ }

Comment: Hi Luvat, you are correct! I added the (document).ready and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code it needs to run when the DOM elements available to find, so `$("#q")` finds the `id="q"` elements to bind to.  This means your script either needs to run *after the elements it needs in the page* (e.g. end of the `<body>`), or when the DOM is completely ready, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#q').click(function() {           
    if($(this).val() == 'Search...') 
      $(this).val('');
  });
});
```

If you're *not* doing this, and the [`$("#q")`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) selector doesn't find any elements...there's just nothing to run [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on, which binds that handler.

I *think* what you'll want is the reverse as well, which would look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#q').focus(function() {           
    if($(this).val() == 'Search...') $(this).val('');
  }).blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') $(this).val('Search...');
  });
});
```

This will put "Search..." back in the box if it's empty and someone clicks outside, by relying on [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) instead of [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: Hi Nick, your 61.5K points are well earned. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnyru/)

You've been faked by google... the textbox has a background which look as if there was value... you should have checked that on the dev tools..

so just try to remove it on blur...

```
$('#q').blur(function(){
    $(this).css('background','none');
    if(this.value == '') {
       this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
}).focus(function() {           
    if(this.value == this.defaultValue) {
       this.value = '';
    }
});​
```